# Highlighting cells when changes are made

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, colors, cell

I am trying to create an Excel Macro Code to highlight any cell yellow when any change is made. I am using the below code and it does work but when I add another line to the sheet I get a Debug error and it is saying there is an issue with the line (If Target.Value <> "" Then ) . Does anyone know why this is happening or if there is another logic I can use instead of the below? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Value <> "" Then

        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: add `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` as the first line.

Comment: Or _handle_ the case where Count > 1

Comment: Basically, VBA cannot equate a string to an array of values.  When there is more than one cell in Target one would need to handle it.  Either exit the sub before the test or iterate the range and test each cell individually.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been searching the web all day! I noticed that the undo button does not work with this Macro. Is there any way to let it work?                            
                                                                                                                                      I also want to create logic to clear those highlights so if you know the code for that, it would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no undo with vba.  As to undoing that try on your own and when you get stuck come back and ask a new question with that code.